# how avoid re rendering using bottom-tabs on react native

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native, mobile

how i can avoid to re render CommonHeader ? which it have the logo , row of social buttons and video player , i want to change just only the content below the player when i browse between the tabs, with this code when i click on homescreen or infoscreen i the emulador looks like is re rendering :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Linking, Image, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome';
import { faYoutube, faInstagram, faSpotify, faFacebook, faTiktok, faTwitter, faWhatsapp } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { faHome, faExpand, faPlay, faShareAlt, faInfo } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import Video from 'react-native-video';

function CommonHeader() {
  return (
    <>
          <StatusBar hidden />

      <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
      <Image source={require('./assets/logo.png')} style={styles.logo} resizeMode="contain" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.socialContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://youtube.com/@xamplemagazine')}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faYoutube} size={16} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://instagram.com/xample_ls?igshid=NTc4MTIwNjQ2YQ==')}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInstagram} size={16} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://open.spotify.com/show/38lBkkl7m4PyypBzotXXdp?si=K36WWz1pTJaNQ7BXL3osfA')}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSpotify} size={16} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://www.facebook.com/xample.ls?mibextid=LQQJ4d')}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebook} size={16} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://www.tiktok.com/@xample_ls?_t=8cD0k5XX1L4&_r=1')}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTiktok} size={16} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://twitter.com/xample_ls?s=21&t=RySOJ8hy2_EDbIo6dLKw_w')}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTwitter} size={16} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.videoContainer}>
        <Video
          source={{ uri: 'https://live.xample.cl/live/livestream.m3u8' }}
          controls={true}
          resizeMode="cover"
          playInBackground={false}
          playWhenInactive={false}
          paused={false}
          repeat={true}
          style={styles.video}
        />
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

function Controls() {
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.buttonRow}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.controlButton}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExpand} size={14} style={{ color: '#92ACE4' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.playButton}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlay} size={20} style={{ color: 'white' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.controlButton}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShareAlt} size={14} style={{ color: '#92ACE4' }} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.titleText}>home</Text>
      <Text style={styles.subtitleText}>lorem ipsum lorem lorem </Text>
    </>
  );
}

function Info() {
  return (
    <Text style={styles.infoText}>Perfil</Text>
  );
}

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <CommonHeader />
      <View style={styles.controlContainer}>
        <Controls />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

function InfoScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <CommonHeader />
      <View style={styles.controlContainer}>
        <Info />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

function App() {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: '#2E87DB',
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#A4AAB7',
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#121421',
            paddingVertical: 10,
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
          },
          headerShown: false
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Inicio"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            unmountOnBlur: false, // Añade esta línea

            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} size={18} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Info"
          component={InfoScreen}
          options={{
            unmountOnBlur: false, // Añade esta línea

            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfo} size={18} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: { alignItems: 'center' , flex:1  }, // Elimina "flex: 1" aquí
  logoContainer: { backgroundColor: '#273264', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%', padding: 10, height:'20%' }, // Reduce el padding aquí
  logo: { width: 100 },
  socialContainer: { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', backgroundColor: '#1D1E2A', width: '100%', padding: 15 },
  videoContainer: { backgroundColor: '#E7E9EE', padding: 20, width: '100%', alignItems: 'center' },
  video: { width: '100%', height: 200 },
  controlContainer: { backgroundColor: '#E7E9EE', width: '100%', padding: 30, alignItems: 'center', height:'100%' },
  controlButton: { backgroundColor: '#E7E9EE', padding: 20, borderRadius: 10 },
  playButton: { backgroundColor: '#273264', width: 60, height: 60, borderRadius: 30, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
  buttonRow: { flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-around', width: '100%', padding: 10, marginBottom: 10 },
  titleText: { fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold', fontSize: 24, color: '#686868', marginBottom: 5 },
  subtitleText: { fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium', fontSize: 14, color: '#686868' },
  infoText: { fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Medium', fontSize: 14, color: '#686868' },
});

export default App;
```

My system :

```
System:
  OS: macOS 13.5
  CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
  Memory: 115.31 MB / 8.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 20.5.0
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.19
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 9.8.0
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2023.08.07.00
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.12.1
    path: /Users/ivanvilches/.rbenv/shims/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 22.4
      - iOS 16.4
      - macOS 13.3
      - tvOS 16.4
      - watchOS 9.4
  Android SDK:
    API Levels:
      - "31"
      - "33"
      - "34"
    Build Tools:
      - 30.0.3
      - 33.0.0
      - 34.0.0
    System Images:
      - android-34 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a
      - android-34 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a
    Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
  Xcode:
    version: 14.3.1/14E300c
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 11.0.20
    path: /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 3.2.1
    path: /Users/ivanvilches/.rbenv/shims/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.3
    wanted: 0.72.3
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```

thanks so much.

Comment: which is the most accurate in this case? useref, usememo or usecallback ?